# How to let the user input number and increase it with a button in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I want to let the user input the `clicks` times and increase it with a button, but I don't know-how.
Here's the code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Click extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicks: 0,
      show: true,
    };
  }


  IncrementItem = () => {
    this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks + 1 });
  };

  DecreaseItem = () => {
    if (this.state.clicks < 1) {
      this.setState({
        clicks: 0,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        clicks: this.state.clicks - 1,
      });
    }
  };
  ToggleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show });
  };
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ clicks: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.DecreaseItem}>Click to decrease by 1</button>
        <button onClick={this.IncrementItem}>Click to increase by 1</button>

        <button onClick={this.ToggleClick}>
          {this.state.show ? "Hide number" : "Show number"}
        </button>
        {this.state.show ? ( <input type="number" name="clicks" value={this.state.clicks}onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>) : (" ")}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Click;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `event.target.value` to number before saving it in state otherwise its just saved as a string

```
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ clicks: Number(event.target.value) });
  }
```

Also replace the input value field to `value={Number(this.state.clicks).toString()}` so that it doesn't keep on showing the leading `0`

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-buck-h241e)**

Comment: This works well, but I can't remove the `0` after I changed the code. Is there any way to remove the `0` and then input the number in?

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The other answer doesn't account for min and max values. Here's my approach (I'm using this for an RSVP form, hence the guest constants)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function RSVP() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
  const maxGuests = 10
  const minGuests = 1

  const handleCount = (e) => {
    if (e > maxGuests) {
      setCount(maxGuests)
    } else if (e < minGuests) {
      setCount(minGuests)
    } else setCount(e)
  }

  const decrementCount = () => {
    if (count > minGuests) setCount(count - 1)
  }

  const incrementCount = () => {
    if (count < maxGuests) setCount(count + 1)
    else if (count > maxGuests) setCount(maxGuests)
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <div className='flex gap-3 py-4 my-3'>
        <input
          type='button'
          onClick={() => decrementCount()}
          value='-'
          className='cursor-pointer'
        />
        <input
          required
          type='number'
          name='counter'
          value={count}
          onChange={(event) => {
            handleCount(event.target.value)
          }}
        />
        <input
          type='button'
          onClick={() => incrementCount()}
          value='+'
          className='cursor-pointer'
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, here's an example using a [function components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

[image: Edit react-component-state-example]

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Click() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);

  const decrementCount = () => {
    if (count > 0) setCount(count - 1);
  };

  const incrementCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const toggleVisibility = () => {
    setIsVisible(!isVisible);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={decrementCount}>Click to decrease by 1</button>
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>Click to increase by 1</button>
      <button onClick={toggleVisibility}>
        {isVisible ? "Hide number" : "Show number"}
      </button>
      {isVisible && (
        <input
          type="number"
          name="clicks"
          value={count}
          onChange={(event) => {
            const value = Number(event.target.value);
            setCount(value);
          }}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This does not work if you manually input a number and then attempt to use in increment buttons- it pushes the new number to the end. If you manually enter 5 and then hit the +1 button, the number changes to 51.

Comment: If you have a min and max**

Comment: @JordyJordyJordyJordan Good catch. I think I fixed it by casting the value of the input to a `Number()` before storing it in state. It's been a few years since I've used CodeSandbox so I'm not 100% if the change saved.